# I'm new to ROS how do I get started?

Tags: ros, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have already installed Ubuntu,ROS,Openni and PCL, my hardwares are iRobot Create Platform, Microsoft Kinect Sensor and a laptop.
So far, I'd like to program by C++, but I don't know what software to program it , could you give me some examples to teach me ,please. Very urgent, please.......

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10388/i%27m-new-to-ros-how-do-i-get-started?/) by [kkhh1122](https://answers.ros.org/users/749/kkhh1122/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-06-24

Post score: -7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-07-03**:
Also please read our guidelines for asking questions: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-06-24**:
Please keep in mind that answers.ros is not a place to hold your hand through every step of the ROS process.  It is a way to get questions answered, and see previous questions that have been asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

start [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) after reading the [general overview](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Introduction)

once you've gone through each tutorial, you'll need to read up on the [navigation stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation)

You'll probably want to [mimic](http://answers.ros.org/question/717/is-an-imu-required-to-run-turtlebot-stack#1243) the configuration of a [turtlebot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot) so you can leverage their pointcloud to laserscan node as well as their teleop and odometry nodes.

---

Originally posted by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) with karma: 1607 on 2011-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8